# Как использовать tarantool в качестве кэша существующей базы?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, tarantool

Добрый день.

Подскажите, есть ли какие-то мануалы по тому, как использовать tarantool в качестве кэша для оракловой базы?

Те статьи, которые выгугливаются, говорят в основном о том, как работать с тарантулом самим по себе.

А вот как настроить его в качестве кэша для уже существующей базы?

Comment: Никак. только руками. Это отдельная СУБД вы можете работать с ней только из своего приложения, в ручную кешируя нужные данные. С другой стороны, зачем кешировать именно оракл целиком, если в оракле можно делать отдельные кеши на нужные таблицы его собственными средствами. А так же in-memory временные таблицы.

Comment: Чтобы он магически встроился в систему и начал кэшировать запросы, а вы не заметили ничего, кроме ускорения производительности? Никак, это так не работает.

Comment: @etki Вот я и хочу разобраться - а как это работает? ))

Comment: Нужно работать с тарантулом самим по себе и отправлять/вытягивать из него данные.

Comment: А более детально все равно никто не скажет, потому что в каждом случае вам решать как это можно использовать исходя из конкретно стоящих задач